# Bamboo build server incorrect log encoding

Tags: java, encoding, locale, bamboo

Bamboo build server creates logs using wrong encoding.
First part of log (which written by bamboo) is in windows-1251 (system locale) second part of log is written from script inside a build task.

but when bamboo shows log in the "Build results" page it tries to render it in utf-8. Why that?

Bamboo writes log file in system locale encoding, but in the web interface it renders log in UTF-8. How to force bamboo use single encoding everywhere?